# Write an SQL query to return the higher rated genre and take the average of those ratings, how can I do this?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to write an SQL query to solve the below problem.

I have two tables:

```
          movies 
id        title       genre 
1         return     Comedy
2         Scooby     Documentary
3         Halo       Documentary



    reviews 
movide_id   rating 
    1        1
    1        3
    2        5
    2        5
    3        3
```

I want to return the best rated movie in each genre, and collect the average score of that movie. So for the above, the expected output would be:

```
genre         title    stars
Comedy        return    2
Documentary   Scooby    5
```

Halo is not there because it is a Documentary, and Scooby is also a Documentary and has higher ratings.

I also need the results to be sorted in ascending order of genre.

A few things I'm not sure on,

I know we use `ORDER BY ... ASC` to sort it.
But not sure about how to create the new columns and the other things.

Comment: I'm at a bit of a loss on this one. Like I know how to do bits of it, but I'm not sure how it all comes together. I know how to sort and use COUNT() and AVG(). But how to break it down into each category and apply these, I'm really struggling on this

Comment: Look into `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Some of them have proprietary syntax that can help *(PostgreSQL, for example, has `DISTINCT ON`)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AS an example of why it's very important to specify your DBMS, this is how short it can be *(using PostgreSQL's `DISTINCT ON` to pick the best movie per genre)*...

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (m.genre)
  m.genre,
  m.title,
  ROUND(AVG(r.rating), 2)  AS stars
FROM
  movies    AS m
INNER JOIN
  reviews   AS r
    ON r.movie_id = m.id
GROUP BY
  m.genre,
  m.title
ORDER BY
  m.genre,
  AVG(r.rating) DESC
```

| genre | title | stars |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Comedy | Return | 2.00 |
| Documentary | Scooby | 5.00 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/PWgWmIBk)

Comment: Thanks Mat for the solution, I am indeed using PostgresSQL, and Distinct ON is an amazing feature in this case

Comment: @dzdsds Just one note; in the event that two or more movies tie with exactly the same average rating, this arbitrarily picks one of them to return. The RANK() based answers return all the ties together.

Answer (score 1):

You first need to pre-aggregate the *reviews* to get their average ratings, this can be a derived table which you join to *movies*; you can then *rank* the movies by stars and return only the top-ranked row for each genre from an outer query.

Using ranking here means you will see both (or more) titles for a genre if they all happen to have the same average rating.

```
select genre, title, stars
from (
  select m.genre, m.title, stars,
    Dense_Rank() over(partition by genre order by stars desc) rnk
  from movies m
  join (
    select movide_id, Avg(rating) stars
    from reviews
    group by movide_id
  ) r on r.movide_id = m.id
)t
where rnk = 1
order by stars;
```

See a [demo Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/_5jyqQU_)

Answer (score 0):

In logical query processing, window functions are processed after aggregate functions, and therefore aggregate functions can be used as parameters to window functions.

```
select
  genre,
  title,
  round(stars, 2) stars
from (
  select
    m.genre,
    m.title,
    avg(r.rating) stars,
    row_number() over(
      partition by m.genre
      order by avg(r.rating) desc
    ) rn
  from movies m
  join reviews r
  on r.movie_id = m.id
  group by
    m.genre,
    m.title
) s
where rn = 1
order by genre;
```

Results:

```
+-------------+--------+-------+
|    genre    | title  | stars |
+-------------+--------+-------+
| Comedy      | return | 2.00  |
| Documentary | Scooby | 5.00  |
+-------------+--------+-------+
```

Try it on [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/PAar7Twa).